# Common voltage when use a battery powered DMM to measure a voltage

Tags: multimeter, common-mode

I'm a little confused by the common-mode voltage in this situation: Assume you use a DMM to measure a signal generator's output voltage, the signal generator is grounded, apprently the DMM is not. If the DMM use a differential input front, then what's the common-mode voltage the DMM see? I've never seen the internal of a DMM, so can someone explain me, how DMM handle this?

Comment: Do you mean a bench or a handheld?

Comment: I mean the ones which powered by battery, that is, no "ground" wires connected. IMHO, most handheld are this type.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the "battery" in the subject line.

Comment: I wonder, if all handheld DMM are actually "floating single-ended"  device?

Comment: Yes they are ! At least, I have not seen any examples of the opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a common-mode voltage to be defined you need 3 wires !
For an explanation about common-mode signals, [go here](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/2045) and scroll down to figure 3:

[image: common mode signal]

Not how there are signals A and B but also a common (ground, 0 Volt) line.

Now look at your handheld DMM in Voltage mode, it will only have 2 connections.  If you would connect these 2 between signal A and signal B you would measure 3 V (4 V - 1 V).

Now look at your signal generator, it also has 2 connections but one is grounded so you are only to either make signal A **or** signal B.

A handheld DMM **cannot** measure the 2.5 V common-mode voltage directly ! It would need to have access to all 3 lines: signal A, signal B and common.

But you can measure the common-mode voltage indirectly. You first measure signal A with respect to ground, this is 4 V. Then you measure signal B which is 1 V. Then you calculate their average:

(4 V + 1 V)/2 = 2.5 V

which is the common mode voltage.

Comment: So, there is no "differential input front" for a DMM, then should no warry about the common-mode voltage problem which exist in differential measurement, right?

Comment: That is correct. I would not say "just forget about it" is always good to be aware of the actual situation so if you're measuring on a differential signal, beware that it is differential. But to measure the differential signal value by itself, in general you do not need to know the common mode voltage.

Comment: That is, normal DMM can't measure differential signal, if I'm going to measure a differential signal, I must know the "common-mode" voltage for safe, right?

Comment: No, a DMM **can** measure the differential signal directly, look in the example above. The differential voltage is the voltage between signal A and signal B, you can measure that directly. You would measure 3 V ! Indeed for safety reasons you would want to know the common-mode voltage. Suppose signals A and B are 1001 V and 1004 V. The differential signal is still 3 V **but** the commonmode signal is now 1002.5 V which can be **deadly** !

Comment: DMM measures differential voltage between two probes, the common mode voltage doesn't affect the differential measuring of DMM, but it can be lethal if the DMM and its probes aren't designed for high voltage - let we have a common mode voltage of 1kV then the dielectric (wire insulator, tip insulator, DMM case) can break while holding th probe, now you get the connection from common mode voltage in your hand, trough your body to the earth.

Comment: Usualy the measuring range of DMM is also the range of common mode voltage, as the major expense of DMM becomes the insulation as the voltage rises, look for CAT III, CAT II,...instruments price range, also price of some HV probe filled with oil you'll get the idea where the price of DMM is hidden.

Comment: Actually, I'm considering make a DMM by myself. When I designed a font with a differential PGA, I find I don't know the the "common-mode" voltage. Because the "ground" of my DMM is the negative of the battery, but the ground of the input signal is others. So I mean "differential font", not only a "differential voltage", sure I know DMM can measure the "differential voltage". I wonder what front the DMM use, single or differential?

Comment: font ? You mean front-end ? Cheap DMMs are usually single ended, expensive ones can be differential. Usually bench multimeters (not handheld) with 4 terminal inputs (extra sense inputs for accurate measuring) have a differential front end. Differential is more expensive so only used when better performance is needed.